# How does Spring know which property file to refer to for getting the value of the variable annotated with @Value?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What if there are multiple property files in our application and both of those files have that variable with different values set?

We usually just inject the value as below and it somehow always manages to get the value form properties file. How?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;
```

Comment: You should take a look to this documentation : [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Spring Boot** [has many possible sources of configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

When it comes to property files it checks for `application.properties` and then `application-<active_profile>.properties` where `<active_profile>` is set by `spring.profiles.active` environment variable (the same holds for `*.yaml` files).

It will search for property files applying the above rule in the following directories in this precedence:
<sup>**(higher on the list overrides** properties loaded from the lower locations)</sup>

- `/config` subdirectory of the current directory
- current `./` directory
- classpath's `/config` package (everything in `src/main/resources/config` if you use maven)
- classpath's root `/` (everything in `src/main/resources` if you use maven)

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: Spring Boot actually uses more than just `application.properties` files. You can see it in this documentation : [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: sure, the question was only about the property files... I will add general discussion about all sources of properties

Answer (score 2):

The value from the last file that Spring reads will overwrite all previously read values. If you define the order in which files are read yourself (via configuration for example) than you have full control over it. Have a look at the follwing examples:

Annotation based config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:foo.properties", "classpath:bar.properties"})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
//...
}
```

XML-based config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties,classpath:bar.properties"/>
```

If `bar.properties` contains properties which are also defined in `foo.properties`, the value from `bar.properties` overwrites the one from `foo.properties`.